# Error with the bumblebee2 package

Tags: ros, bumblebee2, camera-info-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys !

I am getting this error when i try to compile the bumblebee2 package of Columbia University :

---

[ rosmake ] All 32 linesumblebee2: 4.2 sec ]                                                                                                                                      [ 1 Active 45/46 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package bumblebee2
[rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only bumblebee2
Package camera_info_manager was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `camera_info_manager.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'camera_info_manager' found
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/rospack.py", line 45, in call_pkg_config
value = subprocess.check_output(['pkg-config', option, pkg_name])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pkg-config', '--cflags-only-I', 'camera_info_manager']' returned non-zero exit status 1
[rospack] Error: could not call python function 'rosdep2.rospack.call_pkg_config'

CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):

```
Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'bumblebee2'.
Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
broken dependency!
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:227 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)

### -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package bumblebee2 written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/anis/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130329-160036/bumblebee2/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< bumblebee2 [FAIL] [ 4.22 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package bumblebee2.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 46 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/anis/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130329-160036

---

I already installed the camera_info_manager package and it compiles without any failure.
This is what i get with the roscd pkg :

---

anis@anis-Precision-M4500:~/rgbdslam_workspace$ roscd camera_info_manager

anis@anis-Precision-M4500:~/rgbdslam_workspace/sandbox/image_common-groovy-devel/camera_info_manager$

---

I looked for the "camera_info_manager.pc" file in all my system and i don't find it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59552/error-with-the-bumblebee2-package/) by [INSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/4565/insa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2013-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys i fixed the problem by replacing the camera_info_manager by an other one that i found on the version 1.6 of the image_common stack
image_common-1.6/camera_info_manager

---

Originally posted by [INSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/4565/insa/) with karma: 112 on 2013-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0